# aliasing or custom Coreference or Rule based Coref in stanford NLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

How can I do aliasing or custom Coreference or Rule based Coref in Stanford NLP with JAVA.

I have the following use case

"Murugan" can be referred as Arumugam,Sharavan, Kandan

Vishnu can be referred as Narayanan, Narasimhar, Venkatesan

How can do that with the help of Stanford NLP.

I googled it, but didn't get any useful answer, i don't find any documentation for Stanford NLP.

There is RulebasedCorefMentionFinder class, but don't  know how to use it with JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Stanford nlp has co reference resolution. But I am not sure how this could help you. You can go through this link http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml .As you can see in the example mentioned in that link , you can get indirect references like he,she.

Ex :- "Ravi is from India.He is a great writer.He has great taste for music."

In the above sentence 'He' refers to Ravi. By using Stanford nlp , you will be able to identify these type of references.

It don't think there is any tool or documentation in Stanford nlp that could possibly solve your problem.

You could use regular expressions to solve your problem.